# System design email notification service

Tags: architecture, system-design

I need to design a system which will be responsible for sending out emails to users. The trigger can be based on an event by a user e.g. user forgot password or it may also be triggered by the website admin.

In the later case, admin can decide to send an email to a group of people or all the registered users. A use case would be change in privacy policy.

Can you suggest a good design for such scenario assuming the user base is very big and we can't afford to load all the users/emails in memory?

Comment: This is a really broad question.  Can you provide more detail on the environment, current architecture, requirements, frequency of requests - anything that gives people something to analyze?

Comment: @BradIrby, I only have the current requirement as above. Tech: Java, nodejs, Frequency: 10k notification/ min.

Answer (score 0):

user role in your logic, and for introducing role in your system you might need to built RBAC(role based access)